# UDP Client Server unable to exchange messages after port change

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port

I am currently working on a UDP Client-Server program where I am gradually implementing some TCP features above the current UDP ones. An important thing to note is that this code is made to work with a single client so far (implementation for more clients will probably come later).

I have managed to set up the 3 way handshake correctly and messages are correctly exchanged between both the client and the server. I am using the SYN-ACK message to extract a new port number from the server which the client will use to exchange data (in this case simply messages). However, upon finishing the synchronization and changing the port client side, I am unable to keep going with the message exchange and the server never receives the information sent by the client.

Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define DOMAIN AF_INET
#define TYPE SOCK_DGRAM
#define PROTOCOL 0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1025
#define TIMEOUT_SECONDS 1
#define TIMEOUT_MICRO 0

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // INITIALIZATION
    int port_sync, port_data;
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Too few arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./server <port_sync> <port_data>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc > 3)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./server <port_sync> <port_data>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        port_sync = atoi(argv[1]);
        port_data = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    // SELECT RETURN
    int select_return;

    // SOCKET OPTION
    int opt = 1;

    // FILE DESCRIPTOR
    fd_set read_fd_set;

    // SYNCHRONIZATION SOCKET
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset((char*)&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

    int socket_fd;
    if ((socket_fd = socket(DOMAIN, TYPE, PROTOCOL)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Connection error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Synchronization socket created.\n");

    if(setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] setsockopt error");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = DOMAIN;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port_sync);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int socket_length = sizeof(server_addr);

    // SYNCHRONIZATION SOCKET BIND
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Bind error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Binded successfully to port %d.\n", port_sync);

    // DATA SOCKET
    struct sockaddr_in server_data_addr;
    memset((char*)&server_data_addr, 0, sizeof(server_data_addr));

    int socket_data_fd;
    if ((socket_data_fd = socket(DOMAIN, TYPE, PROTOCOL)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Connection error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Data socket created.\n");

    if(setsockopt(socket_data_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] setsockopt error");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_data_addr.sin_family = DOMAIN;
    server_data_addr.sin_port = htons(port_data);
    server_data_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int socket_data_length = sizeof(server_data_addr);

    // DATA SOCKET BIND
    if (bind(socket_data_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_data_addr, sizeof(server_data_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Bind error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Binded successfully to port %d.\n", port_data);

    // CLIENT SYNCHRONIZATION
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_length;

    // CLIENT DATA
    struct sockaddr_in client_data_addr;
    socklen_t client_data_length;
    char* client_data_IP;
    int client_data_port;

    // CONNECTION
    int online = 1;
    int sync_done = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while(online)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);
        if (!sync_done)
        {
            FD_SET(socket_fd, &read_fd_set);
        }
        FD_SET(socket_data_fd, &read_fd_set);

        if (((select_return = select(10, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL))) < 0 && (errno!=EINTR))
        {
            perror("[-] Select error\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(socket_fd, &read_fd_set))
        {
            client_length = sizeof(client_addr);
            bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &client_length);
            if (strstr(buffer, "SYN") != NULL)
            {
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                sprintf(buffer, "SYN-ACK-%i", port_data);
                sendto(socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));

                recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, &client_length);
                if (strstr(buffer, "ACK"))
                {
                    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            }

            printf("Finished synchronization\n");
            FD_CLR(socket_fd, &read_fd_set);
            sync_done = 1;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(socket_data_fd, &read_fd_set))
        {
            int recvfrom_return = recvfrom(socket_data_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_data_addr, &client_data_length);
            if (strcmp(buffer, "") != 0)
            {
                client_data_IP = inet_ntoa(client_data_addr.sin_addr);
                client_data_port = ntohs(client_data_addr.sin_port);

                if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0)
                {
                    printf("[-] Disconnected from %s:%d\n", client_data_IP, client_data_port);
                    close(socket_data_fd);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("UDP Client: %s\n", buffer);
                    sendto(socket_data_fd, buffer, recvfrom_return, 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_data_addr, client_data_length);
                    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define DOMAIN AF_INET
#define TYPE SOCK_DGRAM
#define PROTOCOL 0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1025
#define TIMEOUT_SECONDS 1
#define TIMEOUT_MICRO 0

int get_data_port(char* buffer)
{
    char delim[] = "-";
    char port[20];
    char* ptr = strtok(buffer, delim); // ptr = "SYN"
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);      // ptr = "ACK"
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);      // ptr = port_data
    strcpy(port, ptr);
    int port_data = atoi(port);
    return port_data;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // INITIALIZATION
    int port_sync, port_data;
    char addr[15];
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Too few arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./client <adresseIP> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc > 3)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments given.\n");
        printf("Format: ./client <adresseIP> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(addr, argv[1]);
        port_sync = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    // SOCKET OPTION
    int opt = 1;

    // SYNCHRONIZATION SOCKET
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    memset((char*)&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));

    int socket_fd;
    if ((socket_fd = socket(DOMAIN, TYPE, PROTOCOL)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] Connection error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] Synchronization socket created.\n");

    if(setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
    {
        perror("[-] setsockopt error");
        exit(1);
    }

    client_addr.sin_family = DOMAIN;
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(port_sync);
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    socklen_t socket_length = sizeof(client_addr);

    // CONNECTION
    int online = 1;
    int sync_done = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (online)
    {
        if (!sync_done)
        {
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            sprintf(buffer, "SYN");
            sendto(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));
            recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, &socket_length);
            if (strstr(buffer, "SYN-ACK") != NULL)
            {
                port_data = get_data_port(buffer);
                printf("New port: %d\n", port_data);

                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                sprintf(buffer, "ACK");
                sendto(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));
            }
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            printf("Finished synchronization\n");
            client_addr.sin_port = htons(port_data);
            sync_done = 1;
            socket_length = sizeof(client_addr);
        }
        else
        {       
            printf("UDP Client: ");
            fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
            buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
            sendto(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)& client_addr, sizeof(client_addr));

            if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0)
            {
                close(socket_fd);
                printf("[-] Disconnected from server\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            int recvfrom_return;
            if ((recvfrom_return = recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) & client_addr, &socket_length)) < 0)
            {
                perror("[-] Data reception error");
            }
            else
            {
                buffer[recvfrom_return] = 0;
                printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've checked numerous online examples and tutorials on how to change a port with socket communication and I feel as though I have followed all the guidelines but visibly I am missing something.

**EDIT**

My issue is that the server never receives client messages after I change the port with `client_addr.sin_port = htons(port_data);`. I have checked server-side and the code enters the second `if(FD_ISSET...)` statement. I haven't managed to pinpoint what is causing the message to not arrive.

Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to point out if this is a duplicate (and link the duplicate question as well)!

Comment: This needs more focus on a specific problem. The description is too broad as it is now.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I hope this helps you understand my problem more easily

Comment: In `select_return = select(10, &read_fd_set,` where does "10" come from?

Comment: @SteveFriedl the 10 is arbitrary so far, it could be any other number as long as one client can connect. It will change later on when I modify the code to deal with multiple clients.

Comment: The code appears to rely on `recvfrom` filling the buffer with NUL-terminated strings, but this is a promise the other end would have to make. Recommend looking at the return value from `recvfrom` and doing the NUL byte termination yourself as a safety measure if you're going to treat these buffers as strings.

Comment: No need to both `memset` and `bzero` the same buffer

Comment: This is a lot of code to wade through trying to figure out what it's trying to accomplish.  You're saying that after the client and server synchronize, the server tells the client "Please start talking to me on some other port" ?  Where is that new port number determined? I don't see the server binding to any other ports.  EDIT: Ok, I see it where this is done, but nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: I've checked the `recvfrom_return` value and get -1 which means that nothing is received which is not what I expected

Comment: May be related: https://github.com/apsrcreatix/Socket-Programming-With-C/tree/master/04-udp-echo-client-server

Comment: @SteveFriedl the server has knowledge of both port numbers and binds to both before entering the while loop. Once inside, the synchronization occurs and executes without problem. Once that is done, the server waits for a message with `recvfrom` and once it gets a message, it continues but what is happening is that the client waits for user input, sends the user input (at least I coded it to do so) and the server should receive it but it doesn't

Comment: @MaxMichel Getting -1 means you can check the error number, which might get you closer to what's going on.

Comment: Looking at this again: I recommend that you check the return value / error code from **every networking call** in both client and server.  The OS may well be telling you what's wrong, but your code is not prepared to listen.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SteveFriedl, I'm checking now !

Comment: @SteveFriedl, my recvfrom was giving me a **bad address** error which was actually that my pointer to the address length was unassigned and therefore making the whole code break! Thanks for the simple debugging tip, I forgot the basics after working on this for so long.

Comment: @MaxMichel *"the 10 is arbitrary so far, it could be any other number as long as one client can connect. It will change later on when I modify the code to deal with multiple clients*" - even with one client, passing an arbitrary value will likely fail. Read the documentation, the first parameter of `select()` is meant to be +1 higher than the highest socket descriptor in the `fd_set` struct(s) you give to `select()`. Which in your example would be either `socket_fd+1` or `socket_data_fd+1`, whichever is higher

Answer (score 1):

I needed to initialize both address lengths such as follows:

`socklen_t client_length = sizeof(client_addr);`

`socklen_t client_data_length = sizeof(client_data_addr);`